# Strange jboss console error

Tags: java, maven, jboss, log4j, classloader

I'm creating additional module to already multi-module maven project. And for this one I want everything to be like in other modules(meaning dependencies) just to test hello world, then I'll go do some more complex stuff. And it does print hello world as it should when deployed onto jboss server, but I get some strange error on console, had anyone had similar experience? and how can I fix it? Here it is :

```
15:48:35,789 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR A "org.jboss.logging.appender.FileAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
15:48:35,789 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 
15:48:35,790 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR [BaseClassLoader@9a8d9b{vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/new-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/}] whereas object of type 
15:48:35,790 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR "org.jboss.logging.appender.FileAppender" was loaded by [org.jboss.bootstrap.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@506411].
15:48:35,790 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "FILE".
```

Here is the part of Appender xml

http://pastebin.com/X7Dgdrki

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First check your `<server>/conf/jboss-log4j.xml` for the configuration of the appender named `FILE` (and post it here if you can - that may give us more clues).

Further investigation reveals that `org.jboss.logging.appender.FileAppender` actually implements the interface `org.apache.log4j.Appender`. So this is apparently a classloader conflict. The same class definition (in this case `org.apache.log4j.Appender`), when loaded by two different classloaders, counts as two distinct classes for the JVM.

Is log4j.jar included in your war, or in your server/lib directory? If so, you could try removing it and see whether it resolves the issue.

**Update:** Actually the easiest possible solution is to simply change the type of the appender to `org.apache.log4j.FileAppender` in jboss-log4j.xml.

Regarding log4j.jar, what I mean is that if it is present in your war, it (and a copy of `org.apache.log4j.Appender`) gets loaded by the war classloader (`BaseClassLoader@9a8d9b` in your error message). And this causes the classloader conflict. So if you do not deploy log4j.jar with your war, the error may go away. This is related to Maven only in that the dependency is configured in your pom. For this little experiment, you can simply remove the log4j.jar from your war by hand; if this solves the issue, configure the log4j dependency in your pom as "provided", e.g.:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If log4j.jar is not in your war, it might still be in the server/default/lib directory - please check that and if it is there, try to remove it.

Comment: @Péter Török thank you for your answer I updated my question, I'm building project with maven so I have no problems with jars ..

Comment: adding <scope>provided</scope> did the trick, care to explain why?

Comment: @c0mrade Glad to hear :-) It works because by default, Maven packages all dependencies within the war. The "provided" scope tells Maven that this jar is provided by the target environment so there is no need to include it in the war. For more details see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: I dont have any dependency of log4j and i have not the log4.jar in my war, so what can i do. thanks

Answer (score 3):

We recently came across this problem. We tried the suggestions above and they did not work. So we handled the problem by replacing all log4j imports with a abstract logging interface (we chose org.apache.commons.logging for this) and removing the log4j from the depdenancies.  Then what happens is the actual underlying logging implementation supports whatever JBoss has set.  And if we want to move back to Tomcat (without JBoss) we can just add the log4j jar or whatever logger implementation back into the war.